# In Relax NG, how do I add description to each thing?

Tags: relaxng

I have a massive Relax scheme and I want to generate a documentation for it. But the problem is that the documentation has no description of each tag attribute or choice. Is there a possibility to add some description to each entity in plain English, so that all those descriptions appear on generated documentation pages in a nice way?

Comment: How are you generating your documentation?

Comment: (in general, you'd probably want to use annotations. See http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html#IDA1OZR )

Comment: @RintzeZelle, I convert it first to XSD, then I use oxygen to make the docs.

Comment: No, it won't work, this "a" tag is a error:

Comment: here is what I get:   
/tt.nrg.xml:28:30: fatal: The prefix "a" for element "a:documentation" is not bound.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot about the second xmlns!

Comment: Did you manage? If so, you might want to answer your own question here with an example of what works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate basic documentation from a Relax NG Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487080/how-can-i-generate-basic-documentation-from-a-relax-ng-schema)